# Controller that Get/Create/Update/Destroy on files of the public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

i'm working on a Rails app.
And i'm trying to write a controller that will have access on the files of the Public folder of rails.
And i'm kind a stuck right now.

What i'm trying to do is a get method on my FileController.

That will obtain a variable "path" who correspond to the path of the file to read who is located on the public folder of rails.

And i want to modify routes.rb for when i make a GET request of "/file/path/to/htmlpage" the request sendback to me the content of the file, like a string for an HTML file.

**EDIT:** The problem is that is need REST url like this.

- show  => GET /file/:path
- create => POST /file/:path
- update => PUT /file/:path
- destroy => DELETE /file/:path

So i deleted my old routes and put

```
resources :files
```

And my old routes wad like that

```
  #get "file/:path" => 'file#get', as: :get
  #get "file/create/*path" => 'file#create', as: :create
  #post "file/create/*path/:content" => 'file#create', as: :create_content
  #get "file/update/*path/:content" => 'file#update', as: :update
  #get "file/destroy/:path" => 'file#destroy', as: :destroy
```

My controller is maybe a little bit weird, i need some advice.

```
class FileController < ApplicationController

  # get "file/:path"
  def show
    path = params[:path]
    if File.exists?( Rails.public_path.join( "#{path}.html" ) )
      @content = File.read( Rails.public_path.join( "#{path}.html" ) )
      puts @content
    else
      puts "The file you want to access doesn't exist"
    end
  end

  # get "file/create/:path"
  # post "file/create/*path/:content"
  def create
    path = params[:path]
    content = params[:content]
    if File.exists?( Rails.public_path.join( "#{path}.html" ) )
      puts "The file you want to create already exist"
    else
      File.write(Rails.public_path.join( "#{path}.html" ), "#{content}")
    end
  end

  # get "file/update/*path/:content"
  def update
    path = params[:path]
    content = params[:content]
    if File.exists?( Rails.public_path.join( "#{path}" ) )
      File.write(Rails.public_path.join( "#{path}" ), "#{content}")
    else
      puts "The file you want to update doesn't exist"
    end
  end

  # get "file/destroy/:path"
  def destroy
  path = params[:path]
  if File.exists?( Rails.public_path.join( "#{path}.html" ) )
    File.delete( Rails.public_path.join( "#{path}.html" ) )
  else
    puts "The file you want to delete doesn't exist"
  end
  end
end
```

But now it's not working, i think i have a problem with my routes and my controller that don't communicate in the right way. But i don't see how i have do to it.
I don't have a file model because i don't see the need for what i want to do.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# FileController

def action_name
  #check and filter here your path param, something like:
  path = params[:path].gsub /[^a-z0-9\.\/]+/, ''
  if File.exists?( Rails.root.join( "public/#{path}" ) )
    @content = File.read( Rails.root.join( "public/#{path}" ) )
  end
end
```

Comment: It kind of works the only problem is that in my path variable it don't take the format of the file.

Answer (score 0):

There are several answers to your question that yield different results.

If you want to load the file inside ruby, you can reference the public path like: `Rails.public_path`.  In addition, you can get the root path to your application via `Rails.root`.  That should help you get access to the files you need inside your controller.

However I have to ask: why do you want to do this?  If you simply want to serve up the file, you can let rails do that by default by simply providing the path in the link itself - it will serve up the public files.  In addition, it's quite likely you don't want to push that through your ruby/rails at all, and want to setup your HTTP server to serve the static files for you which will yield a dramatic performance benefit.

Comment: I don't want to serve up the file. The main idea is to build an API on the rails side to have access on the files and with that i'm able to build a js part to work on those files

Answer (score 0):

I would use a model like this:

```
class PublicFile
  attr_accessor :path, :content

  def save(params)
    File.write(params[:path], params[:content])
  end

  def destroy(params)
    File.delete(params[:path])
  end

  def initialize(params)
    @content = File.read(params[:path])
    @path    = params[:path]
  end

  def find(path_or_paths)
    # to implement
  end

  def all
    # to implement
  end

  def update_attributes(params)
    # to implement
  end
end
```

In controller and views you could generate a scaffold `rails g scaffold PublicFile`, you need to move the model before running the scaffold, and then use the above model that manipulates files.

In conclusion, what I mean is to change the DB that an usual Rails model has, with the access to files, this would be done in model logic.